# Replace method used along-side Select-String not working

Tags: powershell

I am trying to search for the string, replace it and then output the file. I believe I have the syntax correct but for whatever reason it is not working. Can anyone spot why or is this even possible?

```
$DesiredTimeoutTime = '<Settings maxTimeout="04:00:00" />'
$path = "C:\Windows\Settings.log" 

$currentTimeoutTime = Select-String -Path $path -SimpleMatch '<Settings maxTimeout=' -CaseSensitive
Write-Host $currentTimeoutTime
(Get-Content $path).Replace((Select-String -Path $path -SimpleMatch '<Settings maxTimeout="'), $DesiredTimeoutTime) | out-file $path
```

It finds the line and path but it is not saving the changes.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. Simply use the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-3.0) operator with an appropriate [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference):

```
$DesiredTimeoutTime = '04:00:00'
(Get-Content $path) -replace '(?<=<Settings maxTimeout=")[^"]*', $DesiredTimeoutTime |
    Set-Content $path
```

`(?<=...)` is a [positive lookbehind assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zerowidth_positive_lookbehind_assertion), which basically means "look for something that is preceded by this pattern".

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the explanation! I am new to PS so you taking the time to answer and teach is much appreciated. This does work and fix my issue - thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what `[^"]*` is?

Comment: I'd suggest to just read the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#character-classes) @Ansgar linked. (I referenced the anchor you might want to read for this specific question, but take the time and read it complete and carefully)